# Any subgroup of f.g. free group with finite index contains a term of lower central series?

Tags: gr.group-theory, combinatorial-group-theory

Hello?
I have some questions in the group theory.
I know that the intersection of the lower central series of a finitely generate free group is trivial.
So I wonder whether every nontrivial subgroup of the free group containsu a term or not.
I've tried, but coudn't have shown or found a counter example.
It may be false. 
Then, how about a finite index subgroup?

Please let me free from this discomfort.

Comment: A finite-index subgroup of a finitely-generated free group is a finitely-generated free group.   An infinite-index subgroup of a finitely-generated free group is an infinitely-generated free group. 

Comment: Any normal subgroup where the quotient is perfect does not contain any term of the lower central series.

Comment: Ryan - your second sentence is only true if you insert the words 'normal' and 'non-trivial'.

Comment: Tyler - why don't you insert your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "no" in both cases.

The terms of the lower central series of a group are verbal subgroups. If we let $\gamma_c(G)$ denote the $c$th term of the lower central series of $G$, then for any groups $G$ and $K$ and any group homomorphism $\varphi\colon G\to K$, we have $\varphi(\gamma_c(G))=\gamma_c(\varphi(G))\subseteq \gamma_c(K)$; and if $\varphi$ is onto, then $\varphi(\gamma_c(G))$ maps onto $\gamma_c(K)$, so that we have equality.

In particular, if $\pi\colon G\to G/N$ is a quotient map, then $\gamma_c(G/N)$ is trivial if and only if $\gamma_c(G)\subseteq N$. That is, the quotient $G/N$ is nilpotent of class at most $c-1$ if and only if the $c$th term of the lower central series of $G$ is contained in $N$.

So let $F$ be a free group, and let $N$ be a normal subgroup of $F$. Then $N$ contains $\gamma_c(F)$ if and only if $F/N$ is nilpotent of class at most $c-1$.

So, for example, if $F$ is the free group on two generators, then there is a normal subgroup of $F$ such that $F/N\cong S_3$; since $S_3$ is not nilpotent, $N$ does not contain any term of the lower central series of $F$, even though $N$ is of finite index.

Comment: Thank you!
Could I ask more?
Then, how about only the case the subgroup H s.t. between H and F, there exist a subnormal series with finite abelian p-groups as factor groups.
Here, F is a finitely generated free group.
(Is the case equivalent to taking a subgroup of F of prime power index?)

Also, I wonder how can I check the including question for not normal subgroups.

Comment: @qkqh: For nonnormal subgroups, look at the core (largest normal subgroup contained in $H$, the intersection of all conjugates of $H$), which is normal. Since the lower central series term are verbal, they are fully invariant, so $\gamma_c(F)$ is contained in $H$ if and only if it is contained in the core of $H$. Note that in my example, with $F/N\cong S_3$, there is a normal subgroup $N_1$, $N\triangleleft N_1\triangleleft F$ such that $F/N_1$ is cyclic of order $2$, and $N_1/N$ is cyclic of order $3$ (i.e., finite abelian $p$-groups). So the answer is still "no".

Comment: @qkqh: However, if all factors are $p$-groups for the same prime $p$, then $F/N$ is a $p$-group, hence nilpotent, so $N$ contains an appropriate term of the lower central series. (Again, you may as well restrict yourself to normal subgroups of $F$).

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: In your latest comment, even if all factors are $p$-groups for the same $p$, $N$ may not normal in 
F, so $F/N$ cannot be a $p$-group. By any chance, do you mean that the core 
of a subgroup of a prime power index is of index a power of the prime index (even in a f.g. free group)?

Comment: @qkqh: I was thinking of $N$ normal in $F$. In general, it is not true that the core of a subgroup of prime power index is of the same prime power: as a counterexample, go again to $S_3$; lift a nonnormal subgroup of index $3$ to get an $H\lt F_2$ of index $3$, whose core $N$ is of index $6$. So, if you are just trying to think about the nonnormal subgroups, the condition you give is *not* sufficient either. Just look for nonnilpotent finite groups that have appropriate subnormal chains to get counterexamples.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Oh, my stupidity... Yes, the two conditions which I said are never equivalent even for a subgroup of prime index.. By your appreciated comments, I may finally catch what I shoud find. For a subgroup $H$ of a f.g. free group $F$ such that $H\lhd H_k \lhd H_{k−1} \lhd \cdots \lhd H_1 \lhd F$ with factor groups of prime-power orders, $\gamma_c(F)\subset H$ if and only if $\gamma_c(F)\subset Core(H)$ if and only if 
$F/Core(H)$ is nilpotent of class at most $c-1$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: So, I should find a nonnilpotent finite group $K$ such that $K=F/Core(H)$ for some $H$ having above subgroup series in $F$.
Um,,, then isn't there a well-known example? I'm trying now, but I think it's really not easy to find such a $K$ to be a core of such subgroup in (some) $F$.
Thank you, thank you again.

Comment: @qkqh: What is the problem with $S_3$? Find a presentation for $S_3$, which gives you a f.g. $F$ and $R$ with $F/R\cong S_3$. Then look at the subnormal (actually normal) series $\{1\}\triangleleft\{(1,2,3)\}\triangleleft S_3$ and lift it to get a subgroup $S$ of $F$ with $R\triangleleft S\triangleleft F$, $F/S$ of order $2$, $F/R$ of order $3$, but $R$ does not contain $\gamma_c(F)$ for any $F$. 

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Ah, I want that all factor groups are finite $p$-groups for some fixed prime $p$. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @qkqh: Then your question is equivalent to asking whether there exists a non-nilpotent group $G$ with a subnormal subgroup $H$ which is core-free and such that $[G:H]$ is a prime power. I don't have an example off the top of my head (nor an argument for why it is impossible).